# How to check an entry is in a section within a for loop

Tags: craft3, entries

I need to display different information depending on the section the entry comes under when I'm displaying all entries within a loop.

Use case - I have a feed which will pull in all entries such as 'Projects' and 'Events' both are sections set up as channels.

I need to display different information relating to each Entry on the front end as they have different fields.

So I need to check if the entry belongs to 'projects' or 'events' within the loop. I can't seem to achieve it.

Current code:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.authorId(authorIds).orderBy('dateCreated desc') %}
                        
      {% if entry in craft.entries.section('projects') %}

      Do something
    
      {% elseif entry in craft.entries.section('events') %}

      Do something different

      {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

This displays nothing? Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check against `entry.section.handle`:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.authorId(authorIds).orderBy('dateCreated desc').all() %}
                        
      {% if entry.section.handle == 'projects' %}

         Do something
    
      {% elseif entry.section.handle == 'events' %}

         Do something different

      {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks James. That works! I had tried something similar to no avail....

`{% if entry.section.name == 'projects' %}`

Comment: If you're ever in doubt about what variables are available to you, a handy trick is to dump out the key names in your template like this: `<pre>{{ dump(entry.section|keys) }}</pre>`

Comment: Good to know, appreciate that